# C# DataSet saving XML issues with Namespace

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, dataset

I'm reading an XML file and XSD schema using DataSet, but when I save
the XML file from DataSet.WriteXML(), the previous Namespace info is gone.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXmlSchema("MySchema.xsd");
ds.ReadXml("MyParams.xml");
```

This is my original XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyParams xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="MySchema.xsd">
```

When I use WriteXML() I get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <MyParams>
```

I have changed the namespace for DataSet like this:

```
ds.Namespace = "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"MySchema.xsd\"";
```

And the result is better but not right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet xmlns="xmlns:xsi=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot; xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=&quot;MySchema.xsd&quot;">
  <MyParams>
```

I've also tried this when I initialize the DataSet

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet("MyParams");
```

but the output is the same - I still have two problems:

1) The namespace is still "NewDataSet" and should be "MyParams" and
has been added as another level above  instead of replacing it.
As well, I need to keep the "encoding="UTF-8" part.

2) I'm getting the double quotes encoded when they should not be
(I have another question addressing this part.)

How can I fix the namespace issue?

Below is my sample XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="MyParams">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="FirstFolder"/>
                <xs:element ref="SecondFolder"/>
                <xs:element ref="Window"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="FirstFolder" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="InUse">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:boolean">
                <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:element name="Window">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Width"/>
                <xs:element ref="Height"/>
                <xs:element ref="Left"/>
                <xs:element ref="Top"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute ref="InUse" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Width">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                <xs:minInclusive value="305"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Height">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                <xs:minInclusive value="242"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Top">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:integer"/>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Left">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:integer"/>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="SecondFolder"/>
</xs:schema>
```

And this is a sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyParams xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Schemas\MyParams.xsd">
    <FirstFolder>C:\TestFolderOne</FirstFolder>
    <SecondFolder>C:\TestFolderTwo</SecondFolder>
    <Window InUse="true">
        <Width>400</Width>
        <Height>400</Height>
        <Left>100</Left>
        <Top>100</Top>
    </Window>
</MyParams>
```

Comment: It looks like  you need include the WriteSchema option. ds.WriteXml(@"c:\temp\test.xml",XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);  I just read and wrote the xml (did not read schema) and the output file format was different from the input.

Comment: WriteSchema is not good as it writes the schema into the xml file whether I load the XSD or not.

Comment: What is wrong with that?  You have a namespace in the file so it knows what the schema is and get its from the namespace.  You don't need to load the xsd.